# Facebook, Notify users of my app updates

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is there a way to notify to the registered users of my application, when an update, new item, or some new content is available?

Do I need some extended permission to do this?

I'm using Javascript SDK and PHP SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request the [email permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) when you authenticate your users.  Then you can email them all you like...

Please don't spam though... That's not very nice.

Comment: Hi Lix thanks for your answer. One more question: When the user accept the email permission, I have an email address to send - by example - weekly notifications? Or I must to send that notifications by a FB way? Thanks

Comment: There is no way for an application to send you an email inside or outside of Facebook.  It's up to you how often you send emails to your users.